# iphone to ipad convert

Tags: iphone

do i need to add all new xib file for ipad?? i mean should i just copy old xib file and make it as Ipad ??

i have a issue , lets say i  made a UILabel according to iphone now when i convert it to Ipad , its just finish at 320 , how to make fit according to ipad ,

**UPDATES**

ok i am doing like this

```
    #ifndef __IPHONE_3_2 // if iPhoneOS is 3.2 or greater then __IPHONE_3_2 will be defined
    typedef enum { // provided by noblemaster ]:-|
        UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone, // iPhone and iPod touch style UI
        UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad, // iPad style UI
    } UIUserInterfaceIdiom;
    #define UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() (([[UIDevice currentDevice].model rangeOfString:@"iPad"].location != NSNotFound) ? UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad : UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    #endif // ifndef __IPHONE_3_2 











                if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

                    NSLog(@" IPAD");
Flag=1

                else


                    NSLog(@" IPhone");
Flag=0
```

**now in all View Controller i am changing  UI like this**

if(Flag==0)
{
UI=1240 by 760 // UI is defined programmatically

}
else
if(flag==1)
{
} UI=320 by 480

**is this good approach kindly suggest**

Answer (score 1):

You can clone an iPhone xib. Open it in Interface Builder then select `File` > `Create iPad Version` or `Create iPad Version Using Autosizing Masks`.

Comment: but how to fix UILabel size as my UIlabel is 320 by 480 ?? should i stick to double the size or i make it separate UI for both??

Comment: Once an iPhone xib is cloned for iPad, they are two separate independent resources. Most likely you are going to adjust the dimension manually. You may still share the same ViewController code among the two xibs, if you prefer to.